# Microsoft Office 2016 drop-down menus are not working

Tags: microsoft-office-2016

I have a problem with Microsoft Office 2016 x64 (system Win 10x64)  - the drop-down menus (like choosing the font color from the top menu, with small dropdown triangle button) stopped working.

Problem: after opening ANY Office app, when I try to hit any of icons in the top menu to show the drop-down menu, the menu appears for a second and then is gone - remains just a shadowed outline of this menu ...
Same story for the right-click menus (like spelling correction) the pop-up menu is simply not appearing.

[image: example from Word]

I have tried to do the Office Repair - it helped after reboot for ca. 1 minute, and then same story ...
lease help !!!

Comment: Are you using any third party software that can control windows appearance, such as Virtual Desktops? Does it happen in other software?

Comment: Checked - nothing which might change the appearance. If only the case of using two monitors ...  ALL other software works as it should ...

Answer (score -1):

The problem was "[Clover v3](http://ejie.me/)" adding tabs to File Explorer
Thanks to LPChip for a hint in the comments.